# Probability of the digits in a number being non-descending

Tags: probability

If I choose a random $16$ digit number, what is the probability that each digit is greater-than or equal-to the previous? Leading 0's are required; numbers are in the range $[0000000000000000-9999999999999999]$.

The total number of possibilities is $10^{16}$.

As the result of a [simple recursive program](http://ideone.com/6Gm1aJ), I believe the number of desirable results is $2042975$, making the probability $0.00000002042975\%$

However, I cannot come up with the mathematics behind it.

Something interesting to note; if I'm doing the same for a random 2 digit number, the solution is $$10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 55$$

Comment: You seem to be allowing $0$'s as initial digits.

Comment: Yes, correct...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of ways of creating a qualifying number is $${25  \choose 9}=2042975$$ 
as you found.

The reasoning is that you can increment $9$ times - possibly before and after the $16$ digits - from $0$ to $9$. Choosing the location of those increments amongst the $16$ digits gives the value above.

For example, the following increment locations ($+$) amongst the digits ($N$):
$$++NN+NNN+N+NN+NNNN+NNN+N+$$
gives the number 
$$2233345566667778$$

Any number that consists of digits that are always greater than or equal to the previous (apologies for confusion, my first framed answer was for *subsequent*) can be represented like this.

Comment: I dont quite understand the 25. I see it's 16+9, but I dont see why. Could you please explain that a little differently?

Comment: @VictorStone example of how the increment positions work added.

Answer (score 2):

*Just another way of explaining:*

Imagine a $10$ sided die being thrown $16$ times, and tallies of $0$ thru $9$ noted.

A tally of $\;\;\fbox{2}\fbox{3}\fbox{0}\fbox{2}\fbox{3}\fbox{1}\fbox{2}\fbox{2}\fbox{0}\fbox{1}\;$, e.g.would mean the number $0011133444566779$

Using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)),$\;\binom{16+10-1}{10-1}$ non-descending tallies are possible,
and dividing by $10^{16}$ will yield the desired probability